# Integrating iframe like a div with scroll

Tags: html, css, iframe

Firstly here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/krish7878/3LAat/158/)

I am trying to integrate a iframe like a div, I know how do this if this was a normal iframe but this iframe has a slider inside it. As a result there are two scroll bars appearing on the right side.

HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="h_iframe">
        <iframe  src="http://isotopethemes.com/slider-test/" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
html,body {height:100%;}
.h_iframe iframe {position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%; height:100%;}
```

Is there any way where I could make the iframe behave like a div so that the page will have a single scroll bar. `overflow:none` would remove the scroll from the iframe.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular instance, with a full page `iframe`, set the `margin` of your body tag to 0:

```css
html,body{
    height:100%;
}
body{
    margin:0;
}
.h_iframe iframe{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="h_iframe">
        <iframe src="http://isotopethemes.com/slider-test/" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're welcome. If any of the posts here has answered your question to your satisfaction, you might consider accepting it :)

Comment: Accepted :). Wanted to do it right after you answered but it asked me to wait for a min and I had to go out.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers already work well in this case, but I would just like to point out that the idea is to make the outer frame "non-existent", rather than making the iframe blend in with the page. This works in this case where the inner iframe is intended to fill the entire page.

However, unfortunately, there is no easy way to do "integrate an iframe like a div" in general (at point of writing).

There is an attribute `<iframe seamless>` that does exactly what you want (embed an iframe like a div), but that doesn't work in any major browser at the moment. See: http://caniuse.com/#feat=iframe-seamless. There are probably some ways to use Javascript to simulate this: e.g. https://github.com/ornj/seamless-polyfill  has the page in the iframe use Javascript to communicate its `scrollHeight` (using `postMessage`) to the outer page, which then uses Javascript to change the height of the iframe so the entire page in the iframe can be shown without scrolling.

Comment: thank you for the detailed explanation, this is exactly what I was looking for. If other answers don't work on my website I'll have to use seamless polyfill file.

Answer (score 1):

Add overflow:hidden to your CSS like this. I tried it in your fiddle and it works.

```
html,body        {height:100%;overflow:hidden}
.h_iframe iframe {position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%; height:100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write css to affect the inner contents of the iframe... but you can add an `overflow: hidden;` to your body.

Comment: thank you but I know that, adding overflow:hidden to body would hide footer of the body.